# Hugoclose.com malware is causing issues in google chrome

Tags: malware, google, chrome, macos

In my MacBook Air, whenever I search something in google, some adds are appearing out of no where and they're hiding the actual search results from google. When I checked the developer tools, I found that they were coming from a http request to `findsearchresults.info` which is being called from another js file from hugoclose.com https://hugoclose.com/22c1fbfd0fc1969766.js. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems Internet is full of very detailed guides on how to remove this specific Hugoclose.com malware manually, but in short it's removed with the very usual methods:

- Remove the browser extensions you are not familiar with (or you have installed recently).
- Remove all search providers you don't want.
- Change the home page if it has been changed.
- If the malware came with some other application, remove that application.

I don't want to link any of the guides as they all are there to promote their own malware removal software.

Comment: I've tried removing some extensions. Once I remove them it doesn't cause the problem for some time. But it appears again even if I didn't install any extension. Now I've uninstalled all the extensions. Let me see if the problem appears again.